# How to get rid of enoent error in react-native development?

Tags: android, react-native, drawer, enoent

I've been getting this error time and again and am really confused about this enoent error in npm while developing react-native app. whenever i resolve enoent package for one package and tried to install another I get this error. Please with you due respect help me see the clear difference in using the package and to avoid getting this error.
code is here:

```
    PS C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\ecom-App-stlwrt> npm install @react-navigation/drawer
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\ecom-App-stlwrt\node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\ecom-App-stlwrt\node_modules\@react-navigation\.drawer.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\ecom-App-stlwrt\node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer' -> 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\ecom-App-stlwrt\node_modules\@react-navigation\.drawer.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\subba-workstation\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-24T12_27_04_997Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem was with the metro bundler which was running in the background. As soon as stoped if and tried installing again, it worked. The same process worked when other package gave error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

1. `npm cache clean -f`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm i`

Please comment if it is not enough.